# Laravel 4 - paginate ignore distinct in Fluent

Tags: laravel, distinct, laravel-4, fluent, pagination

I make fluent request with distinct and paginate. My problem is that the paginate request is execute before disinct request

My Fluent request :

```
$candidates = DB::table('candidates')
            ->select('candidates.*')
            ->distinct()
            ->join('candidate_region', 'candidates.id', '=', 'candidate_region.candidate_id')
            ->join('candidate_job', 'candidates.id', '=', 'candidate_job.candidate_id')
            ->whereIn('candidate_region.region_id', $inputs['region'])
            ->whereIn('candidate_job.job_id', $inputs['job'])
            ->where('imavailable', '1')
            ->where('dateDisponible', '<=', $inputs['availableDate'])
            ->paginate(15);
```

I test my request with DB::getQueryLog()

```
$query = DB::getQueryLog($candidates);
```

$query show that paginate request (with count) for make number page :

```
5 => 
array (size=3)
     'query' => string 'select count(*) as aggregate from `candidates` inner join `candidate_region` on `candidates`.`id` = `candidate_region`.`candidate_id` inner join `candidate_job` on `candidates`.`id` = `candidate_job`.`candidate_id` where `candidate_region`.`region_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `candidate_job`.`job_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `imavailable` = ? and `dateDisponible` <= ?' (length=396)
```

And my request with distinct is execute after paginate :

```
6 => 
array (size=3)
  'query' => string 'select distinct `candidates`.* from `candidates` inner join `candidate_region` on `candidates`.`id` = `candidate_region`.`candidate_id` inner join `candidate_job` on `candidates`.`id` = `candidate_job`.`candidate_id` where `candidate_region`.`region_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `candidate_job`.`job_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `imavailable` = ? and `dateDisponible` <= ? limit 15 offset 15' (length=417)
```

How to do for execute request distinct before the paginate ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blind guess : try

`DB::table('candidates')->...stuff...->get()->paginate(15)`

Real answer: Create your paginator manually:

```php
$candidates = DB::table('candidates')->...stuff...->get();

$paginator = Paginator::make($candidates, count($candidates), 15);
```

Comment: `->get->paginate` it doesn't possible. Paginator it not accepte Object and no return object

Comment: `$paginator = Paginator::make($candidates, count($candidates), 15);` it's oki, it returning the good number view. But, the candidates are all show on page

Comment: Of course, because manual paginator only generate page numbers, you'll have to filter your array yourself (easy)

Comment: inclure filter with beforeFilter ?

Comment: even easier : `$candidates = array_slice($candidates, $start, $count);` http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-slice.php

Comment: Thanks, i do : http://paste.laravel.com/wBc but, now, the paginate on view, it isn't disponible, why ? But, if i modif the number in get, it's working

Comment: Send `$paginator` to the view, and use that to generate the links.

Comment: Thanks, nice :) But i don't understand why, i have one extra page.

Comment: How many records you have, how many do you show per page, and how many pages it gives you ? Also, maybe you slice wrong ?

Comment: I understand why i have one extra page : because http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Pagination.Paginator.html#112 : it is using ceil()

Comment: Doesn't sound wrong to me. 65 records at 15 per page = 65/15 = 4.333 .. so 5 pages. ceil() is fine to me. What are YOUR numbers ?

Comment: 221/15 = 14.73, so, i have 15 pages, but the last pages is empty. because on page n°14, there are juste 13 candidates (not 15)

Comment: Your numbers are wrong: http://paste.laravel.com/wJP What is your slice algorithm ?

Comment: This solution works but it's still a problem that Laravel team needs to fix... what is one to do when running a query of 100,000 + records?  pagination at query level is key there...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     $presenter = new Illuminate\Pagination\BootstrapPresenter($candidates);
     $presenter->setLastPage($totalPages);
?>

@if ($totalPages> 1)
     <ul class="pagination">
          {{ $presenter->render() }}
     </ul>
@endif
```