# Laravel 4.2 Pagination with complex DB query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, pagination

I am new to Laravel 4.2.

I need to do some pagination in my view search result page.

What I am doing is writing this code in the controller -

```
public function getSpecials()
{
    $title = "Specials";

    
    $info = DB::table(DB::raw('`car` , `available_car`, `users`'))
                        ->select('car.car_maker', 'car.car_model', 'available_car.car_price', 'car.car_production_year', 'available_car.car_id', 'available_car.id', 'available_car.current_position')
                        ->where('available_car.car_id', '`car`.`car_id`')
                        ->where('available_car.is_sold', 'no')
                        ->whereRaw('`available_car`.`created_at` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()')
                        ->orderByRaw('WEEK(`available_car`.`created_at`) DESC')
                        ->orderBy('available_car.car_price', 'desc')
                        ->orderBy('users.last_paid_date', 'desc')
                        ->orderBy('available_car.created_at', 'desc')
                        ->distinct()
                        ->get();

    $pagination = Paginator::make($info, count($info), 5);


    //var_dump($pagination );
    
    
    return View::make('specials',compact('pagination'))->with('info',$info)->with('title',$title);
}
```

I want to show 5 items per page. So I am doing paginate like this -

```
$pagination = Paginator::make($info, count($info), 5);
```

But the problem here is I am getting paginate number in the page perfectly.
But, All page is showing the whole result, not showing only 5 items.

It is the output. (paginate is for 5 items per page and total no of entry is 7 in my case)

[image: First Page]

### Page 1

[image: Second Page]

### Page 2

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: What web server are you using? Can you show us how you use url rewrite?

Comment: instead of `get()`, use `paginate(5)`. you have a direct query builder object. you can chain it. if you want to go custom way, you have to again add _skip_ and _take_ and calculate them from the page parameter.

Comment: I am using WAMP server.

If I use paginate() nothing is shown, do I need to change any settings in WAMP server?

We are not using any URL rewrite....

We are using only default laravel pagination

Comment: I am using Paginating in view like {{ $pagination->links() }}

Comment: URI is like http://localhost/car/public/specials?page=2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just make a small change in the code and laravel will take care of the rest.

```
public function getSpecials()
{
    $title = "Specials";


    $info = DB::table(DB::raw('`car` , `available_car`, `users`'))
                        ->select('car.car_maker', 'car.car_model', 'available_car.car_price', 'car.car_production_year', 'available_car.car_id', 'available_car.id', 'available_car.current_position')
                        ->where('available_car.car_id', '`car`.`car_id`')
                        ->where('available_car.is_sold', 'no')
                        ->whereRaw('`available_car`.`created_at` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()')
                        ->orderByRaw('WEEK(`available_car`.`created_at`) DESC')
                        ->orderBy('available_car.car_price', 'desc')
                        ->orderBy('users.last_paid_date', 'desc')
                        ->orderBy('available_car.created_at', 'desc')
                        ->distinct()
                        ->paginate(5);

return View::make('specials',['info' => $info, 'title' => $title]);
}
```

in **view**:

*Iterate like this:*

```
@if(!$info->isEmpty())

    @foreach($info as $i)
    do whatever you want
    @endforeach

@else
   no data to show....

@endif

{{$info->links()}}
```

Comment: Many many thanks for the solution.

But the problem is not all solved perfectly.

If I ver_dump the query result, everything is working.

But if I just send it in the view, then it is not loading anything.

It is just loading and loading again and again, but nothing shown.

CAn you please help me?

Comment: you shouldn't var dump a paagination object.... it will exhaust the memory. if you want to get the items, you can do `$info->getItems()` and it will return you the result. and show your view file.

Comment: Thank you.

I am trying.

Thanks fo the help.

Voitng for this answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to create your paginator manually (Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073971/laravel-4-paginate-ignore-distinct-in-fluent) for more details):

```
$pageNumber = Input::get('page', 1);
$perPage = 5;

$info = DB::table(DB::raw('`car` , `available_car`, `users`'))
                    ->select('car.car_maker', 'car.car_model', 'available_car.car_price', 'car.car_production_year', 'available_car.car_id', 'available_car.id', 'available_car.current_position')
                    ->where('available_car.car_id', '`car`.`car_id`')
                    ->where('available_car.is_sold', 'no')
                    ->whereRaw('`available_car`.`created_at` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()')
                    ->orderByRaw('WEEK(`available_car`.`created_at`) DESC')
                    ->orderBy('available_car.car_price', 'desc')
                    ->orderBy('users.last_paid_date', 'desc')
                    ->orderBy('available_car.created_at', 'desc')
                    ->distinct()
                    ->get();

$slice = array_slice($info, $perpage * ($pageNumber - 1), $perpage);
$info = Paginator::make($slice, count($info), $perPage);
return View::make('specials',['info' => $info, 'title' => $title]);
```

Then print results in a foreach loop like suggested by @itachi.

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer I need, because I'm using DB::select() which returns an array.