# Laravel/Eloquent Paginate returning too many pages and some empty

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following query:

```
return Calls::select(DB::raw("ph_n.`desc`, ph_s.StageName, Calls.PatID, Calls.CallTime, Calls.ApptDate, Calls.Name, ph.Response, Calls.Physician, r.StatusDesc, ph_s.DaysToNextStage, ph_e.ph_eventid, ph_e.EventName"))
        ->join('PopHealth as ph', function($join){
            $join->on('Calls.PatID', '=', 'ph.PatID');
            $join->on('Calls.Login', '=', 'ph.Login');
        })
        ->join('Response as r', 'ph.Response', '=', 'r.RespID')
        ->join('PopHealth_stages as ph_s', 'ph.ph_eventid', '=', 'ph_s.ph_eventid')
        ->join('PopHealth_events as ph_e', 'ph.Login', '=', 'ph_e.Login')
        ->join('PopHealth_notify as ph_n', function($join){
            $join->on('r.status', '<=', 'ph_n.RangeUpper');
            $join->on('r.status', '>=', 'ph_n.RangeLower');
        })
        ->where('Calls.Login', 'demo')
        ->distinct()->take(100)
        ->paginate(10);
```

It is returning 400+ pages and a lot of the pages are empty. Nothing online came up with this problem. Any leads?

**Edit:**

dd(DB::getQueryLog()); spits out the following SQL:

```
array(4) { [0]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(70) "select * from `PopHealth_events` where `Login` = ? and `IsDeleted` = ?" ["bindings"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "demo" [1]=> string(1) "0" } ["time"]=> float(196.17) } [1]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(103) "select distinct `ph_eventid`, `EventName` from `PopHealth_events` where `Login` = ? and `IsDeleted` = ?" ["bindings"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "demo" [1]=> string(1) "0" } ["time"]=> float(217.22) } [2]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(505) "select count(*) as aggregate from `Calls` inner join `PopHealth` as `ph` on `Calls`.`PatID` = `ph`.`PatID` and `Calls`.`Login` = `ph`.`Login` inner join `Response` as `r` on `ph`.`Response` = `r`.`RespID` inner join `PopHealth_stages` as `ph_s` on `ph`.`ph_eventid` = `ph_s`.`ph_eventid` inner join `PopHealth_events` as `ph_e` on `ph`.`Login` = `ph_e`.`Login` inner join `PopHealth_notify` as `ph_n` on `r`.`status` <= `ph_n`.`RangeUpper` and `r`.`status` >= `ph_n`.`RangeLower` where `Calls`.`Login` = ?" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "demo" } ["time"]=> float(192.68) } [3]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(694) "select distinct ph_n.`desc`, ph_s.StageName, Calls.PatID, Calls.CallTime, Calls.ApptDate, Calls.Name, ph.Response, Calls.Physician, r.StatusDesc, ph_s.DaysToNextStage, ph_e.ph_eventid, ph_e.EventName from `Calls` inner join `PopHealth` as `ph` on `Calls`.`PatID` = `ph`.`PatID` and `Calls`.`Login` = `ph`.`Login` inner join `Response` as `r` on `ph`.`Response` = `r`.`RespID` inner join `PopHealth_stages` as `ph_s` on `ph`.`ph_eventid` = `ph_s`.`ph_eventid` inner join `PopHealth_events` as `ph_e` on `ph`.`Login` = `ph_e`.`Login` inner join `PopHealth_notify` as `ph_n` on `r`.`status` <= `ph_n`.`RangeUpper` and `r`.`status` >= `ph_n`.`RangeLower` where `Calls`.`Login` = ? limit 10 offset 0" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "demo" } ["time"]=> float(198.18) } }
```

The SQL is limiting the results.

Answer (score 0):

Did you fix this?

I'm facing the same problem and I found that the culprit is that the distinct is not taken into consideration when laravel's paginate query the DB to find the total count of elements, so the total number of items is much greater.

There is an answer here:  [Laravel 4 - paginate ignore distinct in Fluent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073971/laravel-4-paginate-ignore-distinct-in-fluent)

In short, you have to make your own pagination.